# Does everything inside an Rc copied into the heap?

Tags: rust

I have this Rust code and a doubt come over:

```
fn append(&mut self, value: T){
    match &mut self.next {
        element::Next(v) => v.borrow_mut().append(value),
        element::Nil => {
            let d = DoubleLinkedList::new(value);
            self.next = element::Next(Rc::new(RefCell::new(d)));
        },
    }
}
```

I would like to know if the RefCell containing d is actually copied into the heap. I think it doesn't make any sense to have it on the stack since when the function go out of the scope, the stack will shrink. Is it right?
If it is right, the behavior is quite similar to Box (even if there are other differences).

Comment: `Box` and `Rc` are almost identical, with the difference that `Box` gives **one** owner **mutable** access to the heap object, and `Rc` gives **multiple** owners **immutable** access to the heap object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is heap allocated:

> The type `Rc<T>` provides shared ownership of a value of type `T`, allocated in the heap. Invoking `clone` on `Rc` produces a new pointer to the same allocation in the heap.

Rust's [`rc` module docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html) give even more information in regards to `Rc`'s implementation.